# Interpreting DrMemory log, memory leak

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, mingw, sdl

I wrote a simple snake game using SDL api, and there's a memory leak somewhere in the game, because after about 10 minutes of running the game it takes over 50mb of ram and it's still expanding. I did my best to find the leak but I can't locate it. I tried using Dr Memory, but the log it produces is not fully understandable by me.

Here's the log in question:
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwXrdShTcyjENmgyR2lrbTJ1aGc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Perhaps you might switch to Linux and use `valgrind` ?

Comment: perhaps some code.. it sounds like a loop problem

Comment: according to the logs you have many memory leaks. for example, have a look what is here: `# 5 load_image()                            [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:144]
# 6 load_files()                            [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:192]`

Comment: Yes, I checked whole my code, and to the best of my knowledge there is no memory leak. SDL functions are mostly taken from Lazy Foo' SDL tutorial.

Comment: I wish I could help but solar flares are interfering with my crystal ball. If only there was some non-psychic way of seeing the code in question...

Comment: After calling `TTF_RenderText_Solid()`, you need to call `SDL_FreeSurface()`.

Comment: @user315052 it's like you have that crystal ball Nik Bougalis was talking about. I was uploading the code so he could take a look at it but you were first to give me the solution.
user315052 write it as an answer so I can choose it as the right one.
There are still some leaks in DrMemory, but I'm not sure if I can do anything about them.
Here's the source if someone still wants to take a look at it:
<https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwXrdShTcyjEei1SU21iaWhYMjA/edit?usp=sharing>

Comment: @Krzaku: I just looked at the log that itwasntpete posted. I'll edit his answer, give him credit if you wish.

Comment: You should consider editing your question, and the question description, to make it more acceptable. The question itself is about finding a memory leak, but it is particular to SDL, and the issue was not being able to interpret the Dr. Memory log file. The question description should have included the portions of the log file you did not understand, as well as the link to the complete log.

Comment: Edited it, hope it is ok now. As for the part I didn't understand. I didn't understand the whole log, and some parts of it weren't even caused by my code I think. Now that you explained how you found out what was wrong it will help me in locating leaks in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Dr. Memory log, you can see that you have 3 errors with counts about 2899 times.
The errors are:

```
Error # 154:   2899
Error # 155:   2899
Error # 369:   2898
```

So, if you look at the errors:

```
Error #154: GDI USAGE ERROR: same bitmap 0x46052c24 selected into two different DC's 0x08012c43 and 0xbe012c3e
# 0 SDL.dll!SDL_UnregisterApp      +0x3063   (0x681304c3 <SDL.dll+0x304c3>)
# 1 SDL.dll!SDL_UpdateRect         +0x69     (0x68125d7a <SDL.dll+0x25d7a>)
# 2 SDL.dll!SDL_Flip               +0x52     (0x68125ff3 <SDL.dll+0x25ff3>)
# 3 draw()                          [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:133]
# 4 SDL_main                        [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:92]
# 5 console_main                    [./src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c:315]
# 6 WinMain@16                      [./src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c:398]
# 7 main                            [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:211]
Note: @0:00:04.148 in thread 3940

Error #155: GDI USAGE ERROR: DC 0x08012c43 that contains selected object being deleted
# 0 system call NtGdiDeleteObjectApp
# 1 GDI32.dll!DeleteDC                            +0xb6     (0x75b1596a <GDI32.dll+0x1596a>)
# 2 GDI32.dll!DeleteDC                            +0x11     (0x75b158c5 <GDI32.dll+0x158c5>)
# 3 SDL.dll!SDL_UnregisterApp                     +0x30c9   (0x6813052a <SDL.dll+0x3052a>)
# 4 SDL.dll!SDL_UpdateRect                        +0x69     (0x68125d7a <SDL.dll+0x25d7a>)
# 5 SDL.dll!SDL_Flip                              +0x52     (0x68125ff3 <SDL.dll+0x25ff3>)
# 6 draw()                                         [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:133]
# 7 SDL_main                                       [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:92]
# 8 console_main                                   [./src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c:315]
# 9 WinMain@16                                     [./src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c:398]
#10 main                                           [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:211]
Note: @0:00:04.149 in thread 3940

Error #369: LEAK 60 direct bytes 0x04c09070-0x04c090ac + 0 indirect bytes
# 0 SDL.dll!SDL_CreateRGBSurface         +0x8a     (0x681250cb <SDL.dll+0x250cb>)
# 1 SDL_ttf.dll!TTF_RenderUNICODE_Solid  +0xa6     (0x6f4c2e87 <SDL_ttf.dll+0x2e87>)
# 2 SDL_ttf.dll!TTF_RenderText_Solid     +0x62     (0x6f4c3253 <SDL_ttf.dll+0x3253>)
# 3 draw()                                [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:130]
# 4 SDL_main                              [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:92]
# 5 console_main                          [./src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c:315]
# 6 WinMain@16                            [./src/main/win32/SDL_win32_main.c:398]
# 7 main                                  [L:/git/snake/src/main.cpp:211]
```

It appears that you allocate new memory in some loop, but have forgotten to deallocate.

For error #369, which is labeled LEAK: After calling `TTF_RenderText_Solid()`, you need to call `SDL_FreeSurface()`.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks are caused by wrong **dynamic allocation** usage (or by messing with **pointers**). I guess you haven't used any custom **dynamic allocation** for a small snake game, so I guess you messed something with `SDL_Surface *`.

Check every place where you use `SDL_Surface *`. Do use any code that involves creating (allocating) new **surfaces** in the main game loop?

SDL functions that create (allocate) new **surfaces** generally are `SDL_LoadBMP()`, `SDL_GetRGBSurface()` and `SDL_SetVideoMode()`. Do you use any of them inside main game loop? They generally **SHOULDN'T BE THERE**.

Or maybe you used any dynamic allocation? Check all your **pointers**!

Comment: I eliminated all pointers that weren't needed. The only pointers left are my snake class pointer and a few pointers from sdl. I was basing my SDL functions on Lazy Foo' SDL tutorial.

Comment: Then as I said, check your SDL pointers, they shouldn't be affected by `SDL_GetRGBSurface` and `SDL_LoadBMP` inside main loop. If they aren't, then the snake class pointer is the cause. Do you use `new` for your snake `class` in main loop? If yes, then definitely that's the cause. `new` operator is **dynamic allocation**.

Comment: `new` isn't used anywhere in the main loop.

Comment: No `new`? Do you use `malloc()` or wut? Also, I forgot to mention! `SDL_SetVideoMode()` is also **dynamic allocation**, so it also shouldn't be in main loop!

Comment: No `new` in the loop, I only use new to create my snake class at the beginning of `main`. Well, `SDL_SetVideoMode()` is in `init` function, which is called from the `main` function

Comment: I can't help you then, without seeing your source code. You need to find it yourself.